Review PR in Android Studio and cmd+click around, it is unclear which version of the file is presented
I'm trying to use the PR review option in AS for the first time.
I click on a PR #217 and look at one of the files.
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
I then cmd+click on a param to see usages and click on one of them. Then I am taken outside of the split compare screen, and into full file view.
However, my own branch #219 still appears in the top (the git pull down that shows branches)
[![enter image description here][2]][2]
and when I compare the file to github, it shows the new values from the PR, but nowhere does it indicate that I am looking at the file in the PR version, and not my own branch version.
Did I miss anything? On Github there would be a hash to the version of the file you are looking at. But I could not find anything similar in AS.
Furthermore, I'm not sure how to get back to my own file version on my own branch.
Is this a bug or a feature?
UPDATE: the more I play with it, it's not consistent. Which makes me think it's not fully baked feature. cmd+click will only work in split view, and not in unified. Then sometimes it will take you to usage inside the split view, other times it will take you out and into the full file view where the original issue exists.
[1]: https://i.sstatic.net/822SYeET.png
[2]: https://i.sstatic.net/yVU1FJ0w.png
